# Move Laravel to another server error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to move a laravel project to a new server. Before moving on to the new server I am testing it on localhost.
I am getting the error like this:    `file_put_contents(/megashopping_dk_files/storage/framework/views/d2f79fe2bf4361439b4c43509087ad6167dfffd9.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

The original path in config.php was 
`0 => '/var/zpanel/hostdata/zadmin/public_html/megashopping_dk_files/resources/views',`
which I have changed to 
`0 => '/megashopping_dk_files/resources/views',`

I have already deleted all the files in the folders `cache` `sessions` and `views` in `storage/framework`

Again I have got two root folders with file structure like this:

```
1st root Folder - megashopping_dk
backend
compaign
css
fonts
img
js
library
....
2nd Root Folder - megashopping_dk_files
app
bootstrap
config
database
public
resources
storage
....
```

From the above what I understand is that the 
contents of the First Root Folder should go in the root 
and the contents of the second Root Folder should go alongwith the folder in contains.

Please advise me the right path?

Comment: you don't have any right permission in your `storage/framework` directory. Try giving `755` permission to it.

Comment: I am trying it on windows wamp server. is it needed? and how you will do it in wamp?

Comment: you can just create these 3 folders: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/tree/master/storage/framework

Answer (score 1):

TRY `chmod -R guo+w storage`

Few explanations

`chmod -R guo+w storage` : Whenever we add new service provider the cache folder for that service provider will be created in inside storage/framework . we need to make them writable from our application

`php artisan optimize` : to reuse all frequently used classes php will make an cached class in cache/service.php. So we if add new service we need to run it. We need to use it whenever we add new dependency without using composer.

`php artisan cache:clear` : clear all the above cache and remap everything

For more information read  https://sentinelstand.com/article/laravel-5-optimization-commands

Comment: Hi Sumit. I am really stranger to Laravel. can you please give me a direction where I need to run these commands. for example - to run `php artisan optimize` in which directory I should be in, in the windows command prompt.

Comment: Ok - `php artisan optimize` command was run successfully. and it showed having cleared some cache. Though running chmod command results in `'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Hello - Sumit can you have a look now. I have completely rewritten the question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the cached data. Go to `storage\framework` and remove all the files in `sessions`, `cache` and `views`

Once you are done with that, give proper permissions to your storage folder **recursively**.

Comment: I am on wamp server. Have already removed all files in those folders. still getting the error. however how I will set the permission in wamp, I am not able to make it out.

Comment: Hi I have added some new info in the question. is that helpful?